# Excel sports template rank table

Tags: excel, templates, prediction, euro

I am currently working on a sports template prediction for the upcoming Euro 2020. I haven't gotten that far yet but below is an example of a group. So the "Tecken" column says which team won the game, if there is a 1 there the home team won, if there is a X there it was a draw and if it's a 2 there the away team won. What I would like to do is have a formula in the points column in the second table that checks which is the home team playing and if there is a 1 under the "tecken" column add 3 points to the points table. And if there is a X I would like to add 1 points for that team. I also need to do this for the away teams and add points (if there is a 2 in the "tecken" column) to the points table. Sorry for the bad explanation, is that clearer?

So for spain it would check the first game and see that spain is not playing. It would check the second game and see that spain is the home team and that there is a 1 in the "tecken" column and add 3 points to the points table and so on.

(GF is goals scored by each country and GA is goals scored against each country and GD is the goal difference)

[image: Here is one group example]

Comment: I wrote the text before I saw that you could add the image. But basically what I'd like to do is convert the "tecken" column into points under the points column

Comment: You use many words but the question is not clear. Please edit you question and explain WHAT you want to calculate. Do you want to sum the Tecken column by country? Do you want to count the 1, 2  and X by country? What does GF, GA and GD mean? What is the expected result based on the data you are showing?

Comment: I tried  to explain it a little more clearly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula with CountIFs. Conceptually:

- Count how many times the Home team is Spain AND the Tecken is 1 and multiply by three
- Count how many times the Home team is Spain AND the Tecken is X
- Count how many times the Away team is Spain AND the Tecken is 2 and multiply by three
- add these values together.

Something like this. Adjust the ranges to your sheet.

```
=(Countifs(C:C,K2,I:I,1)*3)+Countifs(C:C,K2,I:I,"X")+(Countifs(E:E,K2,I:I,2)*3)
```

Comment: worked perfectly thank you! I am completely new to excel so did not know countifs existed.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to rank the team from the points column or do I need to add another column for that? I tried with rank() in  the points column but couldn't quite figure it out

Comment: That is a new question. Post it.